# MySQL add columns from query results

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, pivot-table

I'd like to add/create three columns from table column based on this particular column results. This is the records I've in a tblexammarks:

```
SELECT exm.ID, 
       exm.Admission_No, 
       exm.Subject AS 'SID', 
       sb.Name AS 'Subject Name', 
       exm.Term, 
       exm.Test, 
       exm.Marks 
FROM tblexammarks exm 
INNER JOIN tblsubjects sb ON exm.Subject=sb.ID 
ORDER BY exm.ID ASC;
```

**Output:**

| ID | Admission_No | SID | Subject Name | Term | Test | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KBA-2022-003 | 6 | Science | Term One | Test One | 94 |
| 2 | KBA-2022-003 | 6 | Science | Term One | Test Two | 88 |
| 3 | KBA-2022-003 | 6 | Science | Term One | Test Three | 78 |

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:**

| Admission_No | SID | Subject Name | Term | Test One | Test Two | Test Three | Total Marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KBA-2022-003 | 6 | Science | Term One | 94 | 88 | 78 | 260 |

**What I've tried and the output:**

```
SELECT exm.ID, 
       exm.Admission_No, 
       exm.Subject AS 'SID', 
       sb.Name AS 'Subject Name', 
       exm.Term, 
       if(Test='Test One', marks, 0) AS 'Test One', 
       if(Test='Test Two', marks, 0) AS 'Test Two', 
       if(Test='Test Three', marks, 0) AS 'Test Three'
FROM tblexammarks exm 
INNER JOIN tblsubjects sb ON exm.Subject=sb.ID;
```

| ID | Admission_No | SID | Subject Name | Term | Test One | Test Two | Test Three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KBA-2022-003 | 6 | Science | Term One | 94 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | KBA-2022-003 | 6 | Science | Term One | 0 | 88 | 0 |
| 3 | KBA-2022-003 | 6 | Science | Term One | 0 | 0 | 78 |

I've tried using MySQL IF Function but I'm lost. Can someone help.

Comment: I've added the [tag:pivot-table] tag. There are numerous examples on Stack Overflow of doing this type of query with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a conditional statement `IF` and extract the single values for each of the three *Test* fields, then use the `MAX` aggregation function to remove the null values and the `SUM` to get a total for the *Marks* field, then aggregate over the rest of the selected fields using the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT exm.Admission_No, 
       exm.Subject                                          AS SID, 
       sb.Name                                              AS Subject_Name, 
       exm.Term, 
       MAX(IF(exm.Test = 'Test One'  , 'Test One'  , NULL)) AS Test_One, 
       MAX(IF(exm.Test = 'Test Two'  , 'Test Two'  , NULL)) AS Test_Two, 
       MAX(IF(exm.Test = 'Test Three', 'Test Three', NULL)) AS Test_Three, 
       SUM(exm.Marks)                                       AS Marks
FROM       tblexammarks exm 
INNER JOIN tblsubjects sb 
        ON exm.Subject = sb.ID 
GROUP BY exm.Admission_No, 
         exm.Subject AS 'SID', 
         sb.Name AS 'Subject Name', 
         exm.Term
ORDER BY exm.ID ASC;
```

If you can provide sample data from the two tables, I can provide a fully tested solution.